# Way to "include" a file that contains your <head> elements for several pages?

Tags: html, head

My question relates to the  tag in HTML.

I am putting together a project that includes a lot of different php pages/frames. Is there any way I can have one file that can be "included" (for lack of a better term/way) into my  tag that incorporates my several stylesheets/scripts? Reason is I do not want to copy and paste the same scripts over and over and if I find there is one script or stylesheet I forgot to incorporate or I made a typo, I would like to be able to change just that one file.

I am picturing a feature similar to #require where it is like the text is just pasted into the code in replace of that #require when compiled.

Hope the question is clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: This feature lies in PHP (or other such languages), not in HTML.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from using a simple `include`? If you are using a framework it sure has it's own ways to handle that.

Comment: PHP `include "file.php";` where you can store your headers.

Comment: I have tried the <?php include "file.php"; ?> and within that file have pasted my stylesheets and scripts. But it is not bringing in those files, still.

Comment: I am going to agree with @Two-BitAlchemist if there is no other solution and just resort to sadly copying and pasting all my scripts, stylesheets, etc in each head tag haha.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying there's not an _HTML_ tag that can do it. Your `<?php include "file.php"; ?>` will work, but it works **just like C**, by dumping that source code in yours. In other words, `file.php` should contain HTML code (`<head>...<style>...</style><script>...</script></head>` etc.)

Comment: Oh, okay. I had tried that, and contained the HTML code in the file.php, though it did not work. I will try again, and get back to you.